# Correct way to pass async eerror

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a function which uses Firebase auth to update a user's email:

```
export const updateEmail = async (email) => {
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  return user.updateEmail(email);
};
```

It is used in a function which gets an email from a form (in React) and tries to update the email. If there is an error, we change the state to reflect that.

```
handleSave = (e) => {
  const email = e.target.email.value;

  updateEmail(email).catch((err) => {
    this.setState({ didError: true, emailError: err.message });
  });
};
```

However, when an error occurs, in the console I get: 
[image]

My question is: why does this still say 'Uncaught'? Does the `.catch()` in `handleSave` not take care of that?

### update

[Link to relevant Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_email_address)

Comment: I have no experience with firebase, but that looks fine to me as far as catching an error from an async function result (which is a promise).

Comment: where did you use `await` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit where are you suggesting I use `await`?

Comment: You are not returning any error in your async function. I think this why you are not getting any error and an error.message. Also, as asked before you are not using await in your async function. I will try to add an answer.

Comment: @devserkan to clarify, the error message is being set correctly in `this.setState()`.

Comment: But where is that error coming from? Nowhere I guess right now.

Comment: It comes from the error thrown when `user.updateEmail()` fails, as far as I know.

Comment: Then it is also returns a promise. So I guess you need to handle it in your async function. Your async function returns a promise also.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm confused about. Is there no way to "pass" the error on properly, so that it can be used to set the state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming updateEmail returns a prmise, I guess you can try:

```
export const updateEmail = (email) => { // no need for async here
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  return user.updateEmail(email); 
};


handleSave = async (e) => {
  const email = e.target.email.value;
  try{
    await updateEmail(email); 
  }catch(err){
    this.setState({ didError: true, emailError: err.message });
  }
};
```

Comment: Removing the `async` solved the problem here. Thanks! Can you explain why that is?

Comment: Because updateEmail itself does not need to be an async operation since it returns a promise, does not use the data itself. You are using the returned promise in your handleSave function. So, it is async now. Then you are using try/catch to handle the operation. await handling the returned promise and if there is an error returns catch uses it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure since I don't know so much about Firebase, let me suggest something.

```
export const updateEmail = async (email) => {
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    const response = await user.updateEmail(email);
    if ( response.error ) {
        throw new Error( response.error );
    }
    return "something else";
};
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure that code works since I don't know how does auth.currentUser return a response. But somehow if something happens wrong it returns something else like error.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the error is thrown by the `user.updateEmail()` if the email is invalid. Are you suggesting to throw the error in the `.catch()` of that?

Comment: i.e. `user.updateEmail(email).catch(err => throw Error(err))`?

Comment: I've edited my answer but I think we are thinking in the wrong way. You can handle the situation in handleSave as @nikksan suggested. So, updateEmail returns a promise with error rejection properly. How lame I am :)